# How to apply all Html styles to a textview

Tags: android, html

I'm trying to display `HTML` content in a native page. I'm successfully `parsing` the `HTML` content and showing it in a `Textview`. But, Most of HTML styles are not applied to the `Textview`. For example:

```
<p style=\" color:#c9c8cd; font-family:Arial,sans-serif; font-size:14px; line-height:17px; margin-bottom:0; margin-top:8px; overflow:hidden; padding:8px 0 7px; text-align:center; text-overflow:ellipsis; white-space:nowrap;\">
```

Here `color`, `font-amily`, `font-size` and some other attributes are not working.

I used `Html.fromHtml(html)` method for setting the html content.
Is there a way to extend `HTML` class and add these styles to it?

Is there any other alternatives.

Comment: i doubt if  html `font-family` attribute is supported in android!

Comment: then use `android.webkit.WebView`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example:

```
myView.setHint(Html.fromHtml("<small><small><small>" + 
     getString(R.string.hint) + "</small></small></small>"));
```

More detail from here : http://commonsware.com/blog/Android/2010/05/26/html-tags-supported-by-textview.html